# R - Conditional lagging - How to lag a certain amount of cells until a condition is met?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, selection, dplyr

Been trying to solve this for weeks, but can't seem to get it.

**I have the following data frame**:

```
    post_id user_id
1    post-1   user1
2    post-2   user2
3 comment-1   user1
4 comment-2   user3
5 comment-3   user4
6    post-3   user2
7 comment-4   user2
```

And want to create a new variable **parent_id**. So that for each observation it should perform the following steps:

1. Check if `post_id` is either `post` or `comment`
2. If `post_id` is `post` then `parent_id` should equal the earliest `post_id` of the whole data frame.
3. If `post_id` is the first post then `parent_id` should equal `NA`
4. If `post_id` is `comment` then `parent_id` should equal to the first `post_id` it encounters.

**The output should look something like:**

```
    post_id user_id parent_id_man
1    post-1   user1            NA
2    post-2   user2        post-1
3 comment-1   user1        post-2
4 comment-2   user3        post-2
5 comment-3   user4        post-2
6    post-3   user2        post-1
7 comment-4   user2        post-3
```

**I have tried the following:**

```
#Prepare data
df <- df %>% separate(post_id, into=c("type","number"), sep="-", remove=FALSE)
df$number <- as.numeric(df$number)
df <- df %>% mutate(comment_number = ifelse(type == "comment",number,99999))
df <- df %>% mutate(post_number = ifelse(type == "post",number,99999))

#Create parent_id column
df <- df %>% mutate(parent_id = ifelse(type == "post",paste("post-",min(post_number), sep=""),0))
df <- df %>% mutate(parent_id = ifelse(parent_id == post_id,"NA",parent_id))
df <- df %>% select(-comment_number, -post_number)
```

With that code I am able to perform **Steps 1, 2 and 3**, but **step 4** is beyond me. I get the feeling that a certain type of conditional lagging based should be able to solve it, but can't come up with how to do it.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Please post example data, desired output and code that you've tried.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @mtoto I think this should be much clearer now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on your solution,

```
x <- which(df$type == 'post')
z <- which(df$type == 'comment')
df$parent_id[df$parent_id == 0] <- df$post_id[x[sapply(z, function(i) findInterval(i, x))]]
df$parent_id
#[1] "NA"     "post-1" "post-2" "post-2" "post-2" "post-1" "post-3"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sotos! I think I understand it but I am having issues with applying it.

Comment: based on your example data, it should work just by copy-pasting it...what sort of issues are you having?

Comment: Sorry for the previous post accidentally clicked on submit. These are the issues I run into:

The sapply part of this code:
`df$post_id[x[sapply(z, function(i) findInterval(i, x))]]`
Applies the function findInterval(i) that is a post, and applies it to each comment right? 
If I run that part of the code I get a factor with 7 levels 
`[1] post-2 post-2 post-2 post-3`
Which correctly names the posts that should substitute the 0s in parent_id. But when I run the whole line I get:
[1] "NA"     "post-1" "6"      "6"      "6"      "post-1" "7"

Comment: That gives me: `[1] "NA"     "post-1" NA       NA       NA       "post-1" NA`
This is the structure of df:
`'data.frame': 7 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ post_id  : Factor w/ 7 levels "comment-1","comment-2",..: 5 6 1 2 3 7 4
 $ type     : chr  "post" "post" "comment" "comment" ...
 $ number   : num  1 2 1 2 3 3 4
 $ user_id  : Factor w/ 4 levels "user1","user2",..: 1 2 1 3 4 2 2
 $ parent_id: chr  "NA" "post-1" NA NA ...`

Comment: convert `post_id` to character `df$post_id <- as.character(df$post_id)` and it should work

Comment: Done! Thank you very much for your help. Lifesaving. I am still not sure I understand what is going on inside `df$post_id[x[sapply(z, function(i) findInterval(i, x))]]` could you point me out to what topics I should read upon to get an intuitive understanding of it ? 

Thanks again,

Comment: @Flying_Circus look `?findInterval`. It's quite straight forward.